# plsql works in Sql Developer, but not in a liquibase change ORA-06550 PLS-00103

Tags: oracle, plsql, liquibase

I have the following code that has no issue running in SQL Developer, but when I put inside a liquibase change and run it I get an error.

```
DECLARE
  seqval NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(id) + 1 INTO seqval FROM T_SLS_ITEMS;
  execute immediate('CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_SLS_ITEMS MINVALUE '||seqval||'');
END;
```

and the changeset for it:

```
     <changeSet author="Cristian Marian (cmarian)" id="2019-05-24-171101 Fix Items sequence - creting">
        <sql>
          DECLARE
            seqval NUMBER;
          BEGIN
            SELECT MAX(id) + 1 INTO seqval FROM T_SLS_ITEMS;
            execute immediate('CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_SLS_ITEMS MINVALUE '||seqval||'');
          END;
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
```

The error looks like this:

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 27:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
 [Failed SQL: DECLARE
              seqval NUMBER] (Liquibase Update failed.)
```

Comment: Could you please post your changeSet?

Comment: @htshame, sure. I added it. There is a small typo in the id, but not that relevant I guess. :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Liquibase will try to split up the "script" inside the `<sql>` tag by the default statement delimiter which is `;`. For a PL/SQL block this is obviously wrong, as the whole block needs to be treated as single statement.

To achieve that, use [`splitStatements`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) attribute in the `<sql>` tag:

```
<sql splitStatements="false">
  DECLARE 
   .... 
  END;
</sql>
```

Comment: It definitely worked for me.

Comment: I had the same problem while defining a pl/sql block. I declared a variable and did a loop. liquibase tried to add ; anywhere it legally can which can break a pla/sql. Using the suggested solution above it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, dynamic SQL doesn't require statement terminator. I don't know Liquibase, but it seems that it *does* require it.

I'm not sure I understand what you meant by concatenating an empty string at the end:

```
execute immediate('CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_SLS_ITEMS MINVALUE '||seqval||'');
                                                                      ^
                                                                 empty string?
```

How about concatenating a semi-colon instead, i.e.

```
execute immediate('CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_SLS_ITEMS MINVALUE '||seqval||';');
                                                                      ^
                                                                 semi-colon
```

Comment: At this point, I am willing to try anything. That semicolon didn't do it. There were some other params where that empty string is, but I don't need them anymore. Anyway, what I notice is that liquibase is complaining about the declaration of `seqval`. It says that there it would like to have a `;` but there is one and for some reason, it doesn't see it. I've already checked for weird characters in between, found none.

Comment: Would it help if you included something like `<sqlFile endDelimiter=";"/>` into your code?